# Remove multiple commas regex

Tags: php, regex

Can someone please let me know how I would remove multiple commas if they were next to one another in PHP.

```
$address= rtrim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $address_line_1.' '.$address_line_2.', '.$town_village_city.', '.$state_province_county.', '.$postal_code.', '.$country),',');
//return  preg_replace('/([!?,.])+/',' ',$address);
return  preg_replace('!\,+!',' ',$address);
```

For example I may have an address with no town_village so end up with multiple commas.

Also anyone good resources for testing PHP regex?

Comment: Since you can end up with multiple comma-space combinations, you need to replace any sequence of 'comma (optional-spaces comma)' with just comma.  In Perl, you might write `s/,(\s*,)+/,/g` (or, more complexly but with the same overall effect, `s/,(?:\s*,)+/,/g`, using non-capturing parentheses).  The transliteration to PHP might be: `preg_replace(',( *,)+', ',', $address)` but I'm not sure of that.

Answer (score 4):

assuming there are no spaces between these commas, you can simply replace multiple commas with one comma:

```
$cleadAddress = preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $address);
```

although you are replacing every comma with a comma (!), you also replace multiple commas. It depends on your exact data if a more complex regex is worth the effort to save some execution time.

Comment: Any suggestions in Regex for the same challenge?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a proper RegEx for this but here was my work around -

```
$cleanedAddress = str_replace(',',', ',preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $address));
```

Make $address just comma separated, run preg_replace to remove multiple commas, then use str_replace to turn commas to comma space!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be better if you pre-trim and pre-filter the values, then just implode to eliminate this XY Problem.

```
$parts = array_filter([
             trim(trim($address_line_1) . ' ' . $address_line_2),
             trim($town_village_city),
             trim($state_province_county),
             trim($postal_code),
             trim($country)
         ]);
return implode(', ', $parts);
```

---

Otherwise, you can use `/,\K,+/` with an empty replacement string to only replace commas that occur immediately after a comma.

Or if dealing with comma-space sequences, you can use `/, \K(?:, )+/`.