# Remove excess commas from string PHP

Tags: php

I've filtered some keywords from a string, to remove invalid ones but now I have a lot of extra commas. How do I remove them so I go from this:

```
,,,,,apples,,,,,,oranges,pears,,kiwis,,
```

To this

```
apples,oranges,pears,kiwis
```

This question is unique because it also deals with commas at the start and end.

Comment: Show your effort to us to achieve your goal!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove multiple commas regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417951/remove-multiple-commas-regex)

Comment: $link_keywords = preg_replace('/\,/', '', $link_keywords); I tried to do some preg replace but I really don't know enough regular expressions

Comment: did u try it with simple explode() ??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/,+/", ",", $string);
```

basically, you use a regex looking for any bunch of commas and replace those with a single comma.
it's really a very basic regular expression. you should learn about those!

https://regex101.com/ will help with that very much.

Oh, forgot: to remove commas in front or after, use

```
$string = trim($string, ",");
```

Answer (score 8):

Use PHP's [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) functions.

**Steps:**

1) Explode the string with comma.

2) You will get an array.

3) Filter it with `array_filter()`. This will remove blank elements from array.

4) Again, `implode()` the resultant array with comma.

5) You will get commas removed from the string.

```
<?php
$str = ',,,,,apples,,,,,,oranges,pears,,kiwis,,';
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$arr = array_filter($arr);
echo implode(',', $arr);// apples,oranges,pears,kiwis 
?>
```

Comment: I would but I think arrays are heavier than string regex probably :)

Comment: i haven't run benchmarks, but my bet would be that arrays would use more RAM and regexes more CPU, but i think the differences will be neglectible in most cases

Comment: I agree regular expressions are much more faster than use of arrays. I have just proposed an approach.

Comment: Check [Pupil's answer](https://3v4l.org/RVJ0M/perf#tabs) and [@FranzGleichmann answer](https://3v4l.org/0rLEr/perf#tabs)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I dont think so. With complex RegExes, I'd agree with you, but in this ultra-simple scenario, RegEx is much better. Maching a single character repeated any amount of times is so cheap. Explode will perform AT LEAST the same checks than regexp to find the commas, so...

Answer (score 4):

You can also achieve this by using `preg_split` and `array_filter`.

```
$string = ",,,,,apples,,,,,,oranges,pears,,kiwis,,";
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $string);
$filterd = array_filter($keywords);
echo implode(",",$filterd);
```

**Result:**

```
apples,oranges,pears,kiwis
```

**Explanation:**

1. split with comma **","** into an array
2. use array_filter for removing empty indexes.
3. implode array with "," and print.

> [**From Manual:**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) **preg_split** — Split string by a regular expression (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

Answer (score 0):

How about using preg_replace and trim?

```
$str=',,,,,apples,,,,,,oranges,pears,,kiwis,,';
echo trim( preg_replace('@,{2,}@',',',$str), ',');
```